# Going to Bulgaria with Turkish tourist visa. Is this possible?

Tags: visas, bulgaria, ghanaian-citizens

Can I go to Bulgaria with a Turkish tourist visa? I hold a Ghanaian passport. A friend told me I can be arrested and deported to my country. Is this true? Help me out.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=GH&DE=SOF&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database of visa information used by airlines, a visa is required for Ghanaian citizens to enter Bulgaria unless you hold a "C visa issued by Croatia, Cyprus, Romania or a Schengen Member State." Turkey is not one of those. [Bulgaria's Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html) has a page with visa requirements, which confirms this list.

You'll need to [apply for a Bulgarian visa](https://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html) first. It's more likely that you'd simply be sent back if you don't have the required visa (or denied boarding by your airline if traveling by air), but you will not be admitted.